# UIPageViewController Blank Screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a `UIPageViewController` to load multiple `UIViewControllers` but every time I try scrolling past the last `ViewController` or even try scrolling the opposite direction on the start of the `pageController` I get a blank screen as shown below. The blank view is never really fully loaded onto the view but ideally I would like the blank screen to simply have a white colour background hence not obviously visible to the user.

[image: The blank screen appears when I try scrolling to the left from the first VC.]

[image: The blank screen appears again when I try scrolling past the last VC.]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class MainPageVC: UIPageViewController
{
    var totalPages: [UIViewController] = [UIViewController]()

    @IBOutlet weak var rightBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let attributes: [String : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: Constants.defaultFont]
    rightBarButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: .Normal)

       self.delegate = self
       self.dataSource = self

       let eyeWearVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("eyeWear") as! EyeWearVC
       let fitnessVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("fitness") as! FitnessVC
       let healthVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("health") as! HealthVC
       let environmentVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("environment") as! EnvironmentVC

       totalPages.append(eyeWearVC)
       totalPages.append(fitnessVC)
       totalPages.append(healthVC)
       totalPages.append(environmentVC)

       setViewControllers([eyeWearVC], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int)-> UIViewController
    {
       if self.totalPages.count == 0 || index >= self.totalPages.count
       {
           return UIViewController()
       }

       return totalPages[index]
   }

extension MainPageVC: UIPageViewControllerDelegate
{

}

extension MainPageVC: UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
    {
        return totalPages.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
    {
        return 0
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        var currentIndex: Int = totalPages.indexOf(viewController)!

        if currentIndex == 0 || currentIndex == NSNotFound
        {
            return nil
        }

        currentIndex -= 1

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(currentIndex)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        var currentIndex: Int = totalPages.indexOf(viewController)!

        if currentIndex == NSNotFound
        {
            return nil
        }

        currentIndex += 1

        if currentIndex == totalPages.count
        {
            return nil
        }

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(currentIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add
`view.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()`

in `viewDidLoad()`